# Asp.net MVC 4 Ajax post request not working and I can't figure out why

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery

I'm working on an ASP.net MVC 4 application, and in one of the pages I have a form that I am iterating through all the inputs and converting to json data.

Using fiddler, chrome development tools, and firebug I have verified that the data is being converted to json correctly. I am using $ajax to post the data to an mvc controller and every time I do I get an error.

I can't seem to figure out why it isn't working. I'm betting if I could figure out how to get the error message I could figure out how to get this working. When I try to view in the console I don't see the error message. I've tried logging to the console the error message but it doesn't show anything.

If anyone can help me figure out how to get the error message I would appreciate it. I'm also posting the code in case I'm missing something glaringly obvious.

Here is my javascript code:

```
$(function () {

$("#saveform").submit(function () {
    var myRows = [];
    var $headers = $("th");
    var $rows = $("tbody tr").each(function (i, n) {
        var $row = $(n);
        myRows.push({
            id: $row.find('#item_SpecimenId').val(),
            site: $row.find('#item_Site').val(),
            clinicalImpression: $row.find('#item_ClinicalImpression').val(),
            degreeOfSuspicion: $row.find('#item_DegreeOfSuspicion').val(),
            margins: $row.find('#item_Margins :selected').text(),
            count: $row.find('#item_Count').val(),
            lesionSize: $row.find('#item_LesionSize').val(),
        });

    });
    var specimens = JSON.stringify(myRows);
    var url = '/PathSlip/DoctorSlip';
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: '{ id:1, post:2 }',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        statusCode: {
            404: function () {
                $("#response").html('Could not contact server.');
            },
            500: function () {
                $("#response").html('A server-side error has occurred.');
            }
        },
        success: function () {
            $("#response").html('success');
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            $("#response").html('an error');
        }
    });

});
});
```

Here is my viewModel for use in the controller

```
public class SpecimenViewModel
{

    public int id { get; set; }
    public string site { get; set; }
    public string clinicalImpression { get; set; }
    public string degreeOfSuspicion { get; set; }
    public string margins { get; set; }
    public string count { get; set; }
    public string lesionSize { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my mvc controller

```
    public ActionResult DoctorSlip(int id)
    {
        var specimens = _repo.GetSpecimensByBiopsyId(id).ToList();
        return View(specimens);
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DoctorSlip(IEnumerable<SpecimenViewModel> specimens)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("DoctorSlip");
    }
```

Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What a mess.  Why don't you make the Javascript functions calls standalone functions and not nested?  Then you can test them one by one and your code will be cleaner.

Comment: you define an array but in your data object you are just passing a couple numbers.  What are you seeing and what are you expecting to see?

Comment: You're not passing your stringified object.. its expecting a list.. but it is only posting a single object.

Comment: Have you tried the networking tab in the chrome inspector?

Comment: Sorry I was trying a bunch of different things trying to figure this out. I was passing the specimen list which was not working so I changed it to 1 object to see make sure it wasn't my data I was passing in. In the chrome inspector networking tab, other than the loading of my javascript, css and html pages, I see a 302 found status code for the post to my controller and then the loading of the page.

Answer (score 1):

When I used `$.post` instead of `$.ajax` it worked, but I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

i think there is an issue in your code:

You pass the individual field in your "data" i.e. **"id,post"**, while your action method expect list of `SpecimenViewModel` object.  You should pass `specimens` object instead.

First, try sending correct data, and if still the problem persists, just change your return of POST method to `return this.View();` instead of `return RedirectToAction("DoctorSlip");`

I prepare a slight different version from your code which you can try:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("DoctorSlip","Test",FormMethod.Post,new {id="saveform"}))
{
    <!-- your other input controls -->
    <input type="button" id="submitForm" value="Save"/>
}
```

**Script :**

```
<script>
    $(function() {

        $("#submitForm").click(function () {
            var myRows = [];
                myRows.push({
                    id: 1,
                    site: "abc",
                    clinicalImpression: "aa",
                    degreeOfSuspicion: "test",
                    margins: "24",
                    count: "12",
                    lesionSize: "33",
                });

                myRows.push({
                    id: 2,
                    site: "abc2",
                    clinicalImpression: "aa3",
                    degreeOfSuspicion: "test2",
                    margins: "24",
                    count: "12",
                    lesionSize: "33",
                });

            var specimens = JSON.stringify(myRows);
            var url = '/Test/DoctorSlip';
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                data: specimens,
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                statusCode: {
                    404: function() {
                        alert('Could not contact server.');
                    },
                    500: function() {
                        alert('A server-side error has occurred.');
                    }
                },
                success: function() {
                    alert('success');
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert('an error' + thrownError);
                }
            });

        });
    });
</script>
```